# Is this non minified version of jQuery up on Google?

Tags: jquery

During development, I use this to load the latest jQuery:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
```

But during development, I'd like to use the non-minified version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
google.load("jquery", "1", {uncompressed:true});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply include

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can add the `uncompressed` parameter:

```
google.load("jquery", "1", { uncompressed: true });
```

You can even switch automatically:

```
google.load("jquery", "1", { uncompressed: location.host === "dev.yourdomain.com" });
```

Answer (score 1):

During development, why not host it yourself and then move to the Google-hosted minified jQuery?

After all, the impetus for using Google is to reduce initial-load latency for jQuery and during development that isn't really an issue.

Comment: I use non-minified version from Google in development simply because it's easier - I don't have to worry about having a copy on my server and makes switching to a minified version easier (but only ever so slightly) once I'm ready to go live